# Using \hhline to draw double divider lines between rows in table, but how to not start from the beginning?

Tags: tables, tabularx, hhline

[image]

So the current table looks like this, in which I add `\hhline{|=|=|=|=|=|=|=|=|=|}`, however, I would like there isn't a double divider on top of "Method".

I tried `\hhline{=|=|=|=|=|=|=|=|=|}` and `\hhline{==|=|=|=|=|=|=|=|=|}`, but doesn't work.

Comment: Is there really a need for all the double rules, both horizontally and vertically? Why not follow the advice of [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs): "You will not go far wrong if you remember two simple guidelines at all times: 1. Never, ever use vertical rules. 2. Never use double rules."?

Comment: You can try  `\hhline{-::=::=::=::=||=::=::=::=|}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `hhline`  you can use the `~` specifier for 'no line in this column' and the `-` specifier for 'single line in this column'. So the second line would be `\hhline{-|=|=|=|=|=|=|=|=|}`.

However, I agree with the comments that less lines is generally better. In the MWE below four variants, I would prefer the third or maybe the fourth (but definitely not the first).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l||r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hhline{~--------}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Validation} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Testing}\\
\hhline{-|=|=|=|=|=|=|=|=|}
Method & Precision & Recall & F1-score & MCC & Precision & Recall & F1-score & MCC\\
\hline
Naive Bayes & 0.6 & 0.8 & 0.7 & 0.4 & 0.5 & 0.7 & 0.6 & 0.3\\
LSTM & 0.7 & 0.9 & 0.8 & 0.6 & 0.6 & 0.8 & 076 & 0.4\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tabular}{|l|rrrr|rrrr|}
\hhline{~--------}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Validation} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Testing}\\
\hline
Method & Precision & Recall & F1-score & MCC & Precision & Recall & F1-score & MCC\\
\hline
Naive Bayes & 0.6 & 0.8 & 0.7 & 0.4 & 0.5 & 0.7 & 0.6 & 0.3\\
LSTM & 0.7 & 0.9 & 0.8 & 0.6 & 0.6 & 0.8 & 076 & 0.4\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tabular}{l|rrrr|rrrr}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Validation} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Testing}\\
\hline
Method & Precision & Recall & F1-score & MCC & Precision & Recall & F1-score & MCC\\
\hline
Naive Bayes & 0.6 & 0.8 & 0.7 & 0.4 & 0.5 & 0.7 & 0.6 & 0.3\\
LSTM & 0.7 & 0.9 & 0.8 & 0.6 & 0.6 & 0.8 & 076 & 0.4\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrrr}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Validation} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Testing}\\
\hline
Method & Precision & Recall & F1-score & MCC & Precision & Recall & F1-score & MCC\\
\hline
Naive Bayes & 0.6 & 0.8 & 0.7 & 0.4 & 0.5 & 0.7 & 0.6 & 0.3\\
LSTM & 0.7 & 0.9 & 0.8 & 0.6 & 0.6 & 0.8 & 076 & 0.4\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want these double rules, you can also do that with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. This environment creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows and columns and you can use them to draw whatever rule you want with Tikz after the construction of the array.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{NiceTabular}{l!{\hskip1mm}rrrrrrrr}[corners=NW,vlines]
 \Hline
 & \Block{1-4}{Validation} &&&& \Block{1-4}{Testing}\\[1mm]
 \Hline
 Method & Precision & Recall & F1-score & MCC & Precision & Recall & F1-score & MCC\\
 \Hline
 Naive Bayes & 0.6 & 0.8 & 0.7 & 0.4 & 0.5 & 0.7 & 0.6 & 0.3\\
 LSTM & 0.7 & 0.9 & 0.8 & 0.6 & 0.6 & 0.8 & 076 & 0.4\\
 \Hline
 \CodeAfter
   \tikz \draw ([xshift=-1mm]2-|2) -- ([xshift=-1mm]last-|2) 
               ([yshift=1mm]2-|2) -- ([yshift=1mm]2-|last) ;
 \end{NiceTabular}

 \end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]